# LINQ very SLOW when making .toList()

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I'm with a problem i can't solve,

I'm making a simple query in linq:

```
List<MOV> mvs = (from x in new MyAppDataContextSingleton().DataContext.MOV
                                    where x.dateMOV.GetValueOrDefault(x.dateCriation).Date >= initialDate.Date && x.dateMOV.GetValueOrDefault(x.dateCriation).Date <= finalDATE.Date
                                    orderby x.dateMOV
                                    select x).ToList();
```

Execute this query directly on SQL is very fast, it only return about 20 results!
When i execute this query on my project using LINQ is very very slow taking more that 20 seconds :\ but this problem only happens when executing the query to this table. Any idea about what's happening? and how can i solve it?

Best regards,
André

Comment: What does your MOV object look like?  Have you checked the actual SQL this linq query generates?

Comment: I would check and see how much time GetValueOrDefault is using as it is called twice for every item in MOV

Comment: Geoff, yes and if i run the generated SQL in Management Studio it runs fast..

Comment: Phil, the GetValueOrDefault Property is faster and i use it on a lot of another queries like this one.. and works great! :\

Comment: As far as I know you cannot run Linq in SQL management studio. So you need to profile the generated SQL and exectute that in SQL management studio to examine the query plan

Comment: Pleun Yes, when i run in Management is the SQL of the query, and is very fast !

Answer (score 1):

Try turning off Deferred Loading:

```
db.DeferredLoadingEnabled = false;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb386920(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: and what part of this query might be deferred?